# How do I make tpot dashboard work in kibana?

Tags: kibana

I have recently deployed the Tpot honeypot, on my google cloud instance but when I click one of the dashboards to view it shows me an error as shown in the image attached, I have tried everything possible, but unlucky. Could anyone here guide/help me? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thO7z.png)

Comment: Could you please tell us more about how Elasticsearch is integrated with the Tpot honeypot? how data is stored? in what indices? with what mapping? where are those dashboards coming from? what are the indices used in each chart of that dashboard? This would help us understanding your problem :)

Comment: @glenacota Actually, I'm a complete newbie to this, no idea about all of this. I just followed the step by step procedure given on github :) I shall be forever grateful if you can somehow help me

Answer (score 0):

1. tpot is behavior a server
2. after tried a installing tpot, you cannot start another service like elasticsearch/kibana/logstash manually
3. tpot have already deploy inbuild elasticsearch,kibana,logstash[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z02up.png)
4. after installing tpot browse 127.0.0.1:64297->login credential->kibana